Corner radius displays correctly in XML layout but doesn't work on the device
I'm trying to apply corner radius to a MaterialCardView . The corner radius displays correctly in the XML layout editor, but when I run it on an emulator or a physical device, it doesn’t seem to take effect.
Here’s an image for reference:

Here’s the relevant code:
Profile Image Code:
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="80dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/model1" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

Stats Layout Code:
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Overall"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overall_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/overall_score_progress_bar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

Can anyone help me out with this

I removed this lines in my Manifest file and after that my cardviews are worked prefectly fine
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"


This seems like a further information or question. Please put it in comment instead of answer

@manan5439 Any reason for the downvote? Is it illegal to just add a small question within my own answer?

No nothing is illegal. The thing is that adding question in answer doesn't sound right.
Worth editing your question or put it in question's comment. as search engine might rank your question as an answer!

@manan5439 thanks I will take care of it , but please could you remove the down vote , I have removed the small question

awesome, thanks for ur answer.
this worked for me
